# How to join array more than one array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 4 arrays like this:

```
temp1 = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
temp2 = ['d' , 'e' ,'' ]
temp3 = ['f']
temp4 = ['g']
```

I want output:

```
adfg
aefg
afg
bdfg
befg
bfg
cdfg
cefg
cfg
```

and I solved it using following:

```
temp1 = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
temp2 = ['d' , 'e' ,'' ]
temp3 = ['f']
temp4 = ['g']
for list_1 in temp1:
    for list_2 in temp2:
        for list_3 in temp3:
            for list_4 in temp4:
                temp_list = ''
                if list_1: temp_list += list_1
                if list_2: temp_list += list_2
                if list_3: temp_list += list_3
                if list_4: temp_list += list_4
                print "%s " %(temp_list)
```

but I think my code isn't efficient.

How to make good algorithm and make it efficient.

and how about if temp3 is null for example :

```
temp1 = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
temp2 = ['d' , 'e' ,'' ]
temp3 = []
temp4 = ['g']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python Comprehensions. They are cleaner and more elegant.

```
temp1 = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
temp2 = ['d' , 'e' ,'' ]
temp3 = ['f']
temp4 = ['g']

templist = [i+j+k+l for i in temp1 for j in temp2 for k in temp3 for l in temp4] 
# Result - ['adfg', 'aefg', 'afg', 'bdfg', 'befg', 'bfg', 'cdfg', 'cefg', 'cfg']
```

i+j+k+l helps to concatenate strings. Whenever you intend to use items from lists, try using comprehensions.

You can check this out http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> result = product(temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4)
>>> ["".join(item) for item in result]
['adfg', 'aefg', 'afg', 'bdfg', 'befg', 'bfg', 'cdfg', 'cefg', 'cfg']
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If `temp3` is empty as in the updated question, I think you would like to skip it while generating the results. If that's the case, you can only use the list which have some items:

```
>>> input_lists = [arr for arr in (temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4) if arr]
>>> result = product(*input_lists)
>>> ["".join(item) for item in result]
['adg', 'aeg', 'ag', 'bdg', 'beg', 'bg', 'cdg', 'ceg', 'cg']
```

Comment: how about if the array null ??? 
 temp1 = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
temp2 = ['d' , 'e' ,'' ]
temp3 = []
temp4 = ['g']

output will be []

Comment: Yes, it will return `[]` and that is the expected behavior of this function. What do you expect the output to be if there is an empty array?

Comment: I updated the answer in case of empty `temp3` if that's the output which is expected.

Comment: yes , i think it must be filter with 'if' but thank you

Comment: The answer you have accepted would result in `[]` if `temp3` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> result = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4)]
>>> result
['adfg', 'aefg', 'afg', 'bdfg', 'befg', 'bfg', 'cdfg', 'cefg', 'cfg']
```